# laravel not setting session data from first time

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-localization

Alright so I got this locale system with a middleware, the issue is that when I enter language "hu"it doesnt set it the first time, it usualy works only the 2nd time I do it...

**web.php**

```
Route::get('set_language/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    Session::forget('my_locale');
    session(['my_locale' => $locale]);
    return Redirect::back();
});
```

Language.php inside HTTP/middleware

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;

class Language {

    public function __construct(Application $app, Request $request) {
        $this->app = $app;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $this->app->setLocale(session('my_locale', config('app.locale')));

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

And of course I added it inside my **Kernel.php** on couple of spots that seemed correct

```
namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Language::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\Language::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The priority-sorted list of middleware.
     *
     * This forces non-global middleware to always be in the given order.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewarePriority = [
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Language::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    ];
}
```

EDIT: 
I forgot to mention, but in the config/app.php I've set it this way

```
'locale' => 'rs',
'locales' => ['rs', 'hu'],
'fallback_locale' => 'rs',
'available_locale' => ['rs', 'hu'],
```

So now If I got to the `localhost:8000/set_language/rs` it works, but if I do `localhost:8000/set_language/hu` it works only after I do it twice.

I tried dumping the session key `my_locale` and it stays as "rs" until I do the `set_language/hu` twice

So how I do it?
Go to: `localhost:8000/set_language/hu`
Go again to: `localhost:8000/set_language/hu`

Now it works...

Why isnt it being set the first time around?

Just to add up, if you are testing this, try setting your locale to **RS** first and then try to set it to **HU**

Comment: This works just fine for me, can you add the code where you are returning the my_locale session variable?

Comment: @fez now thats weird.. :/ Well the only place I used it was inside the web.php where I've dumped it previously, nowhere else... What did you set as "locale" inside config/app.php ? It could be a mistake there (as it goes for my code). Ive set it as rs

Comment: @fez forgot to mention, look at Edit 2 I've made, try testing it like that. Setting the language to RS first and then try to set it to HU

Comment: @fez doesnt really matter, atleast from what I can see so far. Yeah Im quite sure about it (it works for RS everytime :/ )

Comment: Hmm... The config variable isn't changing. The session variable works, and the middleware is being run. However, if I dump the `my_locale` I see the change everytime

Comment: @fez could it be affected by the redirect? I am dumping the data on the route "/"

Comment: The middleware might not be running on the redirect. When I log the session var and the config var inside the middleware it appears twice, obviously once before the update runs with the old values, and once afterwards with the new values when the redirect back happens. Could you try use something like `logger('Session: ' . session('session_locale'));logger('Config: ' . config('app.locale'));` inside the middleware **after** the the `this->app->setLocale...` logic?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198539/discussion-between-fez-and-tomislav-tomi-nikolic).